# Laravel mailChimp package error

Tags: laravel-5, mailchimp

I try to use the package https://github.com/BlueBayTravel/Mailchimp as in examples but i got an error:

```
ErrorException in Mailchimp.php line 64:
Undefined property: BlueBayTravel\Mailchimp\Facades\Mailchimp::$users
```

when i try to use: Mailchimp::users(), while i can get a connection via Mailchimp::getDefaultConnection(); mean the package is completely red, what u guess the problem with me here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw that you already opened an [issue](https://github.com/BlueBayTravel/Mailchimp/issues/3) in the package repo.

If you are using Laravel, and you want to use an existing integration with Mailchimp, I would recommend you to give a try to the [spatie/laravel-newsletter](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-newsletter) package. It's the most complete package I've found for the integration Laravel + Mailchimp, and it uses the [drewm/mailchimp-api](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api) API wrapper (which IMO, is the best php wrapper for Mailchimp). You can find some examples at [Freek's blog](https://murze.be/2016/04/easily-integrate-mailchimp-laravel-5/) or at the README file of the project. And if you do not find what you need, you can go to a lower level using the drewm wrapper: `$api = Newsletter::getApi();`

If this is not what you are looking for, you can always create your own service in Laravel, adapted to your needs and requierements ;)